# How to validate angular form, having material form field?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I have a form which uses Angular material form fields. I want to disable the submit button, till all the form controls are filled with appropriate value. (code is given as links in the description)

When i am using [material components in template(code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfq2r.png), and [define controls(code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCjwN.png) in components, this is the output.
[image: ok]

#### Problem

When I implement formsBuilder or forms group in [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lvhj.png) and in [component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTCSg.png), the material components won't display properly.

[image]

#### Question

How can I disable/enable submit button only if all the **material forms fiields are evaluated to true**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a form group is the best way to detect if a group of form fields are filled out correctly or not. Have you seen this tutorial? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-material-design-components-with-reactive-form-part-2/

Comment: At the moment you're using a mixture of template driven and reactive forms, so you should settle on one way.

Comment: what do you mean by *When I implement formsBuilder or forms group, the material components won't display properly?* would you mind to elaborate that first.. if you go with `formGroup` everthing will work as expected

Comment: @PankajParkar added screenshots for reference. and the code is kept in links of description.

Comment: @Raj can you check console error when your design breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by making your fields part of a `FormGroup`, like so:

```
group = new FormGroup({
  cNameControl: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
  cDescControl: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
})
```

You can now point the `form` tag at your form group:

```
<form class="example-container" #addCategoryForm="ngForm"  [formGroup]="group">
```

And point your controls at the `FormControl`s:

```
<input matInput placeholder="name" formControlName="cNameControl">
```

*Note that there is no `[` surrounding `formControlName`, because we're using a string literal*

Finally, change your `disabled` tag, so that it's disabled if the form is **not** valid:

```
[disabled]="!addCategoryForm.valid"
```

With all that combined, it should work.

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-skge91?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for taking out time and looking into this. The solution is working. :thumbsup: But the mat-error is not displaying the error description when validation is evaluated to false. The if condition is giving [error](https://i.imgur.com/wPTmUYD.png). Any idea about this?

Comment: defining `get cNameControl() { return this.categoryGroup.get('cNameControl');  }` in component class and defining `*ngIf="cNameControl.hasError('minLength')"` worked. :-) [defining getters in reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)